¿Cómo cambiar el nombre y Favicon de mi página web creada con React?
quiero cambiar el nombre y el icono de mi proyecto creado con react. ¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo?

Lo intenté cambiar en mi archivo de index.html pero no cambia nada
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="./Assets/logo.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="Web site created using create-react-app"
  />
  <title>Laboratorio Clínico Loma Linda Carreño</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>

